# Is there a best way to build a mesh if a bevel is to be applied

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, workflow, bevel

I have been attempting to create a bracket and when I apply a bevel to the object, the corners produce a weird pinched distorted effect. After spending a lot of time trying to alter settings and such I thought perhaps it is actually the construction itself which is causing a problem and that it.So my question is what is the best design/construction method of what is an extremely simple mesh in order for the bevel to work and reduce the possibility of errors. I constructed the bracket by extruding one edge of a plane up 90 degrees and then again 90. I then extruded that object and obtained corners like those shown below which when beveled, produce a distorted finish (also shown below). [image]
[image]

I have actually constructed this mesh three different ways and all have some problem or other with the bevel especially where edges intersect or the mesh bends 90 degree.

Comment: Starting geometry isn't clear, though use Clamp Overlap in modifier's settings  to prevent distorting due to edges coming through each other, (or decrease amount of beveling) and make sure to apply scale to object data (Object mode > Ctrl+A). There isn't best way to construct nearly or anything out there.

Comment: @ Mr Zak Thanks. After playing around with more designs I see that the simpler the design ( less intersecting edges?) the less likely it is to go weird on me! Which is obvious, however It has also made clear that I need to investigate the bevel settings a little more closely.